# Simple installation of native script for use in other recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I need to install a native script, call it `foo`, in one recipe (`foo-native`) and then use it in the `do_compile` step of another (target) recipe - call it `bar`.

My (minimal) native recipe

```
SRC_URI = "file://foo"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit native

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() { 
    : 
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/usr/bin
    install ${WORKDIR}/foo ${D}/usr/bin
}
```

The script, `foo`, exists in a directory called `files` which resides next to the recipe. i.e.

```
foo/
├── files
│   └── foo
└── foo.bb
```

My target recipe for `bar`

```
SRC_URI = ""
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

DEPENDS = "foo-native"

do_fetch[noexec] = "1"
do_configure[noexec] = "1"

do_compile() {
    foo >myfile.json
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/etc
    install ${WORKDIR}/myfile.json ${D}/etc
}
```

The error I get is in the `do_compile` task of `bar`, and it simply says that `foo` can not be found (i.e. has not been installed into a directory on the path).

Comment: I know this is going to be something so stupidly basic that I'm going to be embarrassed by the answer :) I work with Yocto constantly, and think I'm just having a blind spot / senior-moment on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you don't need the line

```
inherit native
```

in `foo.bb`. It's taken care of for you by `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"`.

Secondly, change your `do_install` to:

```
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install ${WORKDIR}/foo ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Note: use `${bindir}` instead of `/usr/bin`. `${bindir}` is determined using `${prefix}`, which in turn is changed e.g. when building a `-native` version of a recipe.

Comment: the bindir-change is the real fix but as an alternative to removing "inherit native" you can also rename the recipe "foo-native.bb", keep the "inherit native" and remove the BBCLASSEXTEND: I'd recommend this for recipes that are intended for native-only as it makes this intent very clear.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should have made it more explicit that the `bindir` change is the fix. Also, having a `foo-native` recipe is a good idea, as long as you don't need the recipe to build for either the target, nor the SDK... Thus, you could need a recipe with `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"` for lots of things.

Comment: @Anders Thanks - knew it would be something simple. I was focused on the wrong part of the recipe. And, of course, the recipe for `bar` needs similar fixes. Renamed to `foo-native` but kept the `BBCLASSEXTEND` to add `nativesdk`